# jQuery zClip isn't copying values to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, zclip

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".process").click(function() {

    var enter = $(".enter").val();
    out = parseFloat(enter) + Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

    $('.enter').attr("value", out);

    $('.process').fadeOut(0);
    $('.copy').fadeIn(0);

    });
});

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".copy").click(function() {

    $(".copy").zclip({
        path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:function() { return $(".enter").val(); },
        afterCopy: afterCopy()
    });

    function afterCopy() {
        $(".enter").val('');
        $('.copy').fadeOut(0);
        $('.process').fadeIn(0);
    }

    });
});
</script>

<form class="form-wrapper cf" action="">
    <span>Enter A Number</span> <br />
    <input type="text" class="enter" size="15" />
    <button type="button" class="process">process</button>
    <button type="button" class="copy" style="display:none;">copy</button>
</form>
```

jQuery zClip plugin don't works in my code.

I want to copy the value resulting from first function [ jQuery(".process").click(function() ] several times as a loop.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npYBm/

Plugin page: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Any solution ? Thanks.

**Problem Solved**

Comment: Problem Solved - HOW?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-wrapper cf" action="">
    <span>Enter A Number</span> <br />
    <input type="text" class="enter" size="15" />
    <a class="" id="copy-button" href="#">Copy</a>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
jQuery(function() {

    $("#copy-button").zclip({
        path:'http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:function() {return $(".enter").val(); }
    });
});
```

The problem was you were placing zClip function inside click event. That is not required.

If you right click the 'copy' anchor tag, you can see flash is attached to it. I think its not happening in the case of input type submit button. That was another problem.

Comment: Hi Dexter, thanks so much for your answer.
Also the problem is: I need a button to make "switch" with show() and hide() not a link.
You know how to get rid of flash attachment ?

Comment: @Vlad, Simply browsers cannot access clipboard due to security reasons. That is why they are using flash to access clipboard. Once I have used zeroclipboard and styled the link button so that they will appear as buttons. You can do show/hide effects on links as you did on buttons too. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I understand. I will try to solve this problem.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're copying the value of a non existent '.link' element
2. `fadeOut(0)` is the same as `hide()`
3. The object must be visible on load
4. As I see it zCopy adds a click event so assigning it inside a click event is redundant

[This version](http://jsfiddle.net/npYBm/3) works but I'm not quite sure exactly why.

Comment: Firs I want to thank you Thomas for your answer.
But I need a button to make "switch" with show() and hide() - not two buttons.
Also in this version flash is attached to copy button.
This is not a final solution.